# DatePicker - want to show input after FormatException

Tags: wpf, datepicker

Is it possible to show input in DatePikcer after FormatExcetpion?

For example user try to type "abcd" in DatePicker.   FormatExcetpion occur, I mark DatePicker as invalid and show some informtaion "please use format ...." but I also want to show the user input in DatePicker.

After FormatExcetpion I have "abcd" in DatePicker.Text but dont know how to make it visible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible :(
If you find something - please let me know here ))